# What is the impact of Ability-Score-changing items on one-shot character creation?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, character-creation

One-shot adventures often include allowances for magic items for the characters (2 uncommon and 1 rare, for a typical example).

These items are:

- Headband of Intellect (Int = 19)
- Gauntlets of Ogre Power (Str = 19)
- Amulet of Health (Con = 19)
- Giant Belts (Strength = 21 to 27)

What is the impact on the sessions if we allow players to choose items like this?

Comment: That is very broad and needs some clear parameter to give you any kind of educated breakdown. What is the specific scenario? This includes levels, atmosphere, group dynamics, setting for the one-shot etc.

Answer (score 2):

The first answer is: "it depends" on your style as a DM and as players and on the PC creation method you are using.

Without further clarification, I can only give generic answers.

- In practice, you are allowing the characters to have a very high score in one ability instead of choosing an other magic item that can be useful for the adventures. Depending on your game style, that can be balanced or not.
- In any case, PCs will be "more heroic" (i.e., have higher stats) than they should be but *the temporary ability scores cannot be used to multiclass* (https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/sac/sage-advice-compendium#SA074)
- The impact will be higher at lower levels were stats (and magic items) are very important. With the increase of the levels, the PCs ability will kick in and the impact will be lower.
- If your campaign is "high-magic" oriented probably the impact will be balanced quickly and in line with the rest of the items they will have/find
- Moreover, please note that the above mentioned objects require attunement so in the long term PCs need to choose what to keep and what to drop.

Answer (score -2):

### These items can be game-changing, particularly if character attributes can be built around them.

Let's first discuss the normal use of these items.

Normally, a party finds a magic item and then decides or rolls to see who gets to keep it. None of the 19 ability items are appealing to a character with an ability score of 18; the character gives up an attunement slot for no real gain (maybe a bit of carrying capacity?). Fighters and barbarians will generally take their strength to 20, rendering Ogre Gauntlets rather worthless, but some characters can get a fantastic gain - for example a Paladin that has invested in Charisma instead of strength or a Rogue who wants better Investigation ability. Maybe a front-line character needs more Constitution, or maybe it's a caster who is targeted often while concentrating. These decisions are usually made at the party level and tend to be fairly obvious as to what character needs them the most. Giant Belts are a little different in that the benefit really goes to characters who are using strength to hit things. There's nothing stopping a Wizard from having a Strength of 23, but it's probably not the optimal choice for the party. So, that party can choose to:

- allow a character with a weak score to now have a good score (I played a gnome Illusionist who had Ogre Gloves for quite a while until he came up with better uses of attunement slots, and it was fun role-play mostly)
- allow a character who can use the score to help the party the most to have a good score
- anything in between.

The key is that in a normal campaign, these items are generally awarded randomly, and during the character build process one would never assume you would get one of these. When you get to choose them as part of character creation, **these items allow a one-shot player to game the system by having ability scores a normally-progressing character would not have.**

In a regular campaign, you wouldn't build a character that had a low primary attribute, but if you can choose one of these magic items, it's easy enough to make your starting attribute 8, which allows flexibility in the rest of the scores. An 8 Str Paladin with Gauntlets is very good. An 8 Str Paladin without them (assuming not a Dex build) is borderline unplayable. The same goes for the other items in different ways.

If the goal of the one-shot is to allow players to theory-craft the most powerful build they can, including the use of magic items, then there is no problem in allowing these items.  If the goal is to present characters that are representative of normally-created ones, these items should be restricted by the DM.  An alternative would be to not allow the items on a primary stats or to only allow them for scores that were already at least 13 in a secondary stat.

Comment: It might be worth noting that using stat adjustment items for primary class stats may prevent any kind of multiclassing which is one of the methods used to optimise characters. It can also be a problem if the character happens to run into an antimagic field.

Comment: We encourage Q&As, but you are generalising a lot in your answer that isn't appliable to many scenarios and caters to a specific style of play.